# How to enable TLS 1.1 or Tls1.2 in Java 7

Tags: community, java, tls

I am using salesforce soap API i has activated tls 1.1 in SF-->Critical updates

i am getting this error

> UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.

I am using **java 7 update 79**.
My sample code for testing TLS.

```
public class TestSaleforce {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnexpectedErrorFault, ApiFault {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = "abc";
        String password = "abc";
        String authEndPoint = "https://tls1test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0/";
        try {
            /* ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
              config.setUsername(username);
              config.setPassword(password);       
         */
            System.out.println("AuthEndPoint: " + authEndPoint);
            //config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
            SoapBindingStub binding = null;
            binding = (SoapBindingStub) new SforceServiceLocator().getSoap();
            binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, authEndPoint);
            LoginResult rs = null;
            rs = binding.login(username, password);
            // Print user and session info
            GetUserInfoResult userInfo = rs.getUserInfo();
            System.out.println("UserID: " + userInfo.getUserId());
            System.out.println("User Full Name: " + userInfo.getUserFullName());
            System.out.println("User Email: " + userInfo.getUserEmail());
            System.out.println(rs.getServerUrl() + rs.getSessionId());
            //  System.out.println("SessionID: " + config.getSessionId());
            // System.out.println("Auth End Point: " + config.getAuthEndpoint());
            // System.out.println("Service End Point: " + config.getServiceEndpoint());
            binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, rs.getServerUrl());
            SessionHeader sh = new SessionHeader();
            sh.setSessionId(rs.getSessionId());
            binding.setHeader(new SforceServiceLocator().getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(), "SessionHeader", sh);
            QueryOptions qo = new QueryOptions();
            System.out.println(new Date() + " SETTING Query Batch Size");
            qo.setBatchSize(new Integer(2000));
            binding.setHeader(new SforceServiceLocator().getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(), "QueryOptions", qo);
            QueryResult qResult = null;
            String soqlQuery = "select RecordType.Name,Email,HasOptedOutOfEmail,Owner.Name,Owner.Email,BMS__leadOpp__r.Name,Id from lead WHERE (RecordType.Name='') AND IsConverted=FALSE";
            qResult = binding.query(soqlQuery);
            boolean done = false;
            if (qResult.getSize() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Logged-in user can see a total of " + qResult.getSize() + " contact records.");
            }
        } catch (RemoteException | ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And other thing i wanted to add is, It is working fine with java 8. So please help me out to enable TLS 1.1 on java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Use this as a command line parameter while running your Java 7 application

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

It works for me and I no longer get the error. You can refer to the official documentation [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https).